# Is there a better way to select an element which is not a sibling of the interacted one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You could find a demonstration of my idea at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hwdfz/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        Div2
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <div class="div4">
            <a href="#">Div4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        Div2
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <div class="div4">
            <a href="#">Div4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.div3 a').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click',function(){
        $(this).parents('.div1').find('.div2').css('background','#FF0000');    
    });
});
```

I don't think reaching it's parent is not very effective. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.closest` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

```
$('.div3 a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.div1').find('.div2').css('background','#FF0000');    
});
```

If you are sure about the structure, you could also go back to `.div3` only and select its siblings:

```
$(this).closest('.div3').siblings('.div2').css('background','#FF0000');
```

Comment: You are right. Makes more sense to use closest(). Thanks a lot =)